# What does the 'shows user location' option of Map View do?

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have checked the 'Shows User Location' option of Map View in my storyboard.
I am using the simulator and do not have access to a real device. When I run the code I can see the blue icon in my map defaulted to California as you expect.

I was wondering whether this blue icon updates on a real device? Does it move when the user is moving?

Or is there additional code that must be put in to make it work?

Comment: You might also want to set `userTrackingMode` to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow` or `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` in the code if you want the map to follow along as the user moves.

Comment: @Rob - What do you mean? Essentially a user will walk around and I want the blue icon to follow them where they go so they know where they are in relation to my annotations. Gabriele below said that is all I need...? Please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: The question is whether the map stays fixed and the blue dot moves around on that map (`MKUserTrackingModeNone`), or whether the user's blue dot stays in the middle of the screen and the map in the background moves in order to follow the user and keep the blue icon positioned in the middle of the map view (`MKUserTrackingModeFollow`). And on devices that support headings (i.e. a compass), `MKUserTrackModeFollowWithHeading` takes it a step further, so that "up" in the map is generally the direction the device is pointing towards.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to say that this is a non issue for me. I would like it to work like a normal map that I have on my phone. Such as apple maps/google maps. If I walk around I can move the map and the blue icon can move. Thanks.

Comment: Very good. Note, these maps apps let the user toggle between "tracking mode none" and "tracking mode follow" (usually by tapping on the little arrow button, though the UI is slightly different in these two apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storyboard option correspond to the `showsUserLocation` property of `MKMapView`. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/showsUserLocation) (emphasis added)

> This property does not indicate whether the user’s position is actually visible on the map, only whether the map view should try to display it. Setting this property to YES causes the map view to use the Core Location framework to find the current location and try to display it on the map. **As long as this property is YES, the map view continues to track the user’s location and update it periodically**. The default value of this property is NO.

Of course, this assumes location services are on and the user granted the app the access to them.

Comment: Yes it is. No extra code is required, unless you need to do something extra like rotating the map with the heading, as Rob suggested already.